# Scrape HTML Table with Python and Dealing with Hidden Rows

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am looking to scrape the HTML table from this page:**
https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shooting/

I normally accomplish this task with a `pd.read_html()` call, but I am having trouble with this particular table. I think it is because there is extra data hidden within the HTML that is not being displayed in the actual page load (data I am not really interested in). I have tried a few of the different parameters in the `read_html` function, but have not had any luck. Those can be found here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

For more details as requested. I did follow the common sense and more advanced routes for retrieving the page soup. Including:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)` and `driver.get()` for the selenium route.

`page = requests.get()` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')` for the non-selenium route.

After which I used `table = soup.find('table')` to retrieve the table HTML to pass to `pd.read_html()`. both methods resulted in a pretty scrambled table which I am not used to getting.

Comment: What code have you tried already? What is your current code? What are the errors? What is the desired output? What is the actual output?

Comment: I have just tried variations of `pd.read_html()`. From my experience, outside of specifying a header row, that immediately will convert the data to a pandas dataframe, which is the desired output. I didn't add any additional code because normally that one line is all that it takes.

Comment: As far as the error goes, I am not getting an "error", the table is just clearly not being converted one-to-one to a pandas df.

Comment: So your entire code was ```pandas.read_html("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shooting/")```? And you got no errors?

Comment: I added additional code for you. But there is nothing special going on hear. I am simply getting the soup of the webpage. I am sorry that you feel like I did not provide enough information.

Comment: It's not about finding something "special" in your code. It's important for people helping you to know what is going on. In the future, post at least minimally reproducible code with actual and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code or current output, it's hard to show where you went wrong or what was causing your issues. This worked for me:

```py
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shooting/")
table = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
head = table.find_element_by_tag_name("thead").find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[aria-hidden='false']")[-1].text
tab = table.get_attribute("outerHTML")
df = pd.read_html(tab)[0]
df.columns = head.split()
final = df[:30]
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! Well where I went wrong with my code was what I was missing. I didn't know that selenium had a way to parse html without actually going through beautiful soup. The `.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[aria-hidden='false']")[-1].text` was exactly what I needed!